# Django 4.x - Conditional order_by of a QuerySet

Tags: python, django

### The Objective

The objective is to conditionally order a QuerySet by one of three different date fields in the view based on another field in the model. Since conditional ordering cannot be accomplished with Class Meta I am exploring accomplishing this objective in the view.

Here is the relevant excerpt from `models.py`:

```
READING_PROGRESS = [
    ('---', '---'),
    ('1) On Reading List', '1) On Reading List'),
    ('2) Reading In Progress', '2) Reading In Progress'),
    ('3) Completed Reading', '3) Completed Reading'),
]

class ReadingProgress(models.Model):
    record = models.ForeignKey(
        LibraryRecord,
        related_name='record_in_reading_progress',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Library record'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    reading_progress = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        choices=READING_PROGRESS,
        default='---'
    )
    date_added = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=False,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    date_started = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=False,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    date_completed = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=False,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = [
            'reading_progress',
        ]
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reading Progress'

        unique_together = ('record', 'user',)

    # Record metadata
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.record.title} - {self.reading_progress}'
```

The relevant fields in the model are:

- `reading_progress`
- `date_added`
- `date_started`
- `date_completed`

Each date field corresponds to a status value. I want to be able to order_by the QuerySet in the view by the field `reading_progress`:

- When `reading_progress` == '1) On Reading List' then order by `date_added`
- When `reading_progress` == '2) Reading In Progress' then order by `date_started`
- When `reading_progress` == '3) Completed Reading' then order by `date_completed`

### Research This Far

I did some research and found a useful looking QuerySet API called, `annotate()`. This looks to be way to go ([Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)).

However, my implementation is not working. Here's what I currently have in `views.py`:

```
        reading_progress = ReadingProgress.objects.filter(user__username=self.request.user)\
            .annotate(
            date_to_display=Case(
                When(reading_progress='1) On Reading List', then=F('date_added')),
                When(reading_progress='2) Reading In Progress', then=F('date_started')),
                When(reading_progress='3) Completed Reading', then=F('date_completed')),
                output_field=DateField(),
            )
        ).order_by(
            'date_to_display'
        )
```

The Django docs appeared to suggest that:

- I could filter
- and then annotate on the filtered QuerySet
- With additional research I concluded that I could use `F()` as a way of implementing the query within the `annotate()` API

However, my implementation is not quite working. This is the Traceback reporting a NameError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 73, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 119, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 174, in get
    context = self.get_context_data()
  File "/app/web/library/views.py", line 1280, in get_context_data
    reading_progress = ReadingProgress.objects.filter(user__username=self.request.user).annotate(date_to_display=Case(When(reading_progress='1) On Reading List', then=F('date_added')),When(reading_progress='2) Reading In Progress', then=F('date_started')),When(reading_progress='3) Completed Reading', then=F('date_completed')),output_field=DateField(),)).order_by('date_to_display')

Exception Type: NameError at /reading_list/
Exception Value: name 'Case' is not defined
```

I feel like I am close but am currently scratching my head. The example snippets I have seen make use of `Case` but for some reason I'm getting an error saying I've not defined `Case`. This leads me to believe that maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: I've rolled this back to the version before you added the answer to the question. In adding the answer, you also deleted the error message, which makes it harder for someone else having this problem to find this question. Please don't add the answer to your question, if you want to add information, either edit it into the answer, or add your own with the additional details.

Comment: Thanks. Still learning my way around SO. :)  I'll edit the answer onto the end.

Comment: The standard on SO is to [keep answer(s) out of the question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262807/7517724) If you think something is missing from the existing answer, add your own answer, don't edit your question to include the answer. Please stop editing the answer into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import the relevant parts within `views.py`

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, Q, Value, When
```